# Angularjs input is not changing when updating via JS and not manual

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, binding

I have a simple form, when I type in the input, i see the changes.
But when I do it dynamically via JS the bind is not changing:

```
    <div ng-app>
        type here and see how the binding changes: 
<input type="text" id="test" ng-model="name" />
        <br /><br />
        Changes and binding <span style='color:red'>{{name}}</span><Br /><Br />

       <button onclick="document.getElementById('test').value = 'blaaaa'">Click and see how the binding is not changing</button>
    </div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hge2hnc4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is because, when you click the button you try to change the textbox value not the textbox model(`name`) value, if you change the model `name` value you will be able to see the update

[Here is a forked Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/j155np2f/)